# What are the names of the vehicles to provide assistance to aircraft during the turnaround?

Tags: ground-operations

During the turnaround many vehicles support the aircraft on the gate. What are the name of those "vehicles"and their purpose?

Comment: there are a lot of different vehicles, list style questions like this are not a good fit for SE in general.

Comment: In my experience, almost all of them are referred to as "tugs", since they are usually pulling or pushing something (luggage carts, the aircraft, etc).

Comment: I wouldn't say that @RonBeyer, there's follow-me cars, catering lifts, luggage ramps, etc. I agree this is a bit broad.

Comment: Fuel trucks, food trucks, snow plows...

Comment: @GdD Yeah, forgot about those ones. VTC though for being too broad.

Comment: Try [this diagram](http://www.boeing.com/commercial/aeromagazine/articles/qtr_3_08/img/figure3.jpg)

Comment: I was about to post an answer with [this information which provides names](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oIALf.png), but I see @TomMcW already provided a best one. See also on Wikipedia: [Ground support equipment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ground_support_equipment). You may also search videos for "[turnaround timelapse](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JMpUy7EyKcY)". Come on, this question isn't "too broad" and it's actually a very interesting one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most common vehicle seen is the *tug*.

[image]
<sup>[source](http://i.bnet.com/blogs/westjettug230412co.png)</sup>
[image]
<sup>[source](https://i.pinimg.com/236x/f3/e6/a7/f3e6a7029cf040fae7a9c708d13b42d2--ground-support-equipment-tractors.jpg)</sup>

Tugs are multipurpose tractors that are used to tow around all sorts of things.

---

Several types of equipment are shown in this diagram:

[image]
<sup>[source](http://www.boeing.com/commercial/aeromagazine/articles/qtr_3_08/img/figure3.jpg)</sup>

---

The tow vehicle at the nose is more commonly referred to as a *pushback tug*. They come in different sizes. Here is an example:

[image]
<sup>[source](http://mms.businesswire.com/media/20140502005881/en/414058/5/TUG_GT110_Push.jpg)</sup>

---

The GPU is most often a unit that is towed behind a tug.
[image]
<sup>[source](https://www.aerospecialties.com/app/uploads/2015/03/TLD_GPU-28-CUP_DC_05.jpg)</sup>

---

Belt loaders usually can be driven on their own:

[image]
<sup>[source](https://www.copybook.com/img/pgib3063s5751/airport-conveyor-belt-loader.jpg?v=1463492964)</sup>

---

The wide loader is used to put cargo containers in the hold:
[image]
<sup>[source](http://planetgse.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/cargo-loader.jpg)</sup>

---

The cabin cleaning truck and galley service truck often have a lift built in:

[image]
<sup>[source](http://shop.narcotictests.com/images/products/catering-cabin-cleaning-trucks-ct6000-motorized.jpg)</sup>

---

Luggage can be brought in baggage carts

[image]
<sup>[source](https://www.aerospecialties.com/app/uploads/2015/03/CBC-5010_Par-Kan_Closed-Baggage_Cart_02.jpg)</sup>

or in cargo containers which are brought to the aircraft on dollies
[image]
<sup>[source](https://sc01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1qyErPFXXXXcdaXXXq6xXFXXXX/201537494/HTB1qyErPFXXXXcdaXXXq6xXFXXXX.jpg)</sup>

---

Another vehicle often seen is the people mover:

[image]
<sup>[source](https://www.copybook.com/img/pgis4968s7922/bradshaw-electric-vehicles-villager-6-personnel-carrier.jpg?v=1463492995)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

In general, you could refer to most of the vehicles and their attachments/trailers as ground support equipment (GSE)

Comment: This does answer half of the question only. What is their purpose?

Answer (score 0):

The vehicle is usually called a ground tug.

Comment: There are many other vehicle types used too.

Comment: Turnaround does not refer to physically turning the plane around ;)